# Query Regarding Character Operations

Tags: c, character

Please explain the following piece of code..

```
   printf("%c\n",0+'0'); --> returns 0
   printf("%c\n",1+'0'); --> returns 1
   printf("%c\n",0+'1'); --> returns 1
   printf("%c\n",1+'1'); --> returns 2
```

Thanx.

Comment: how about google, wikipedia, ... before you ask here?

Comment: @Holger: Please specify a google query which would return a useful answer using only elements of the code above.

Comment: @Aaron: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ is the first google hit with keyword printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). '0' has code 48. So '0' + 1 yields 49, which is '1'. So every character is in fact an integer. You add another integer to it and then, because you specify "%c" in printf, you force it to consider it a character. He goes check his ASCII table and, after some deliberation he decides to print the output to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` gives the `ASCII` value of char `0` which is `48`. To that you add `0` to get `48`. Then you print `48` back as a character which gives `0`

Similarly the next one adds `1` to `48` to give `49` which when printed as char gives `1`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `%c` all of them print the character equivalent of the argument.

```
printf("%c\n",0+'0');
```

Adds zero to the ASCII value of the character zero which is 48: 48 + 0 = 48.
Try `printf("%d\n", '0');` to get the ASCII value.

```
printf("%c\n",1+'0'); // 1 + 48 = 49 which is the character `1`
printf("%c\n",0+'1'); // 0 + 49 which is again `1`
printf("%c\n",1+'1'); //left as an exercise
```

Comment: @RBA Just as an FYI, normally in SO you thank a person by up-voting his answer - by pressing the up-arrow towards the left side of the answer. This will give him/her 10 reputation points. (I've made this answer CW so that I won't earn any rep on this answer; didn't wanna sound begging for rep - just wanted to let you know the custom)